# firebaseAuth GoogleAuthProvider() signInWithRedirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, firebase-authentication

I've a authentication Google with redirect in my app, and I would like just redirect when authentication is completely finished.
But the promise is not working

```
 function loginGoogle() {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function (result) {
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            if (result.credential) {
                var token = result.credential.accessToken;
                console.log('token ' + token);
            }
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
            console.log('user ' + user);
            // if success redirect to
            $state.go('maps-fullwidth');

            // ...
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            console.log(errorCode);
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // The email of the user's account used.
            console.log(errorMessage);
            var email = error.email;
            console.log(email);
            // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
            var credential = error.credential;
            console.log(credential);
            // ...
        });
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Move the `getRedirectResult()` call out of your `loginGoogle()` function. `getRedirectResult()` should be called on page load. An example of this in action can be found here:

https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/google-redirect.html

Comment: can we call it like this `this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(provider).then(() => {
   return this.afAuth.auth
    .getRedirectResult()
    .then(result => {
     console.log(result);
     const that = this;
     this.storage
      .set(TOKEN_KEY, result.user.refreshToken)
      .then(res => {
       that.authenticationState.next(true);
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
     alert(error.message);
    });`

Comment: on a then callback in `signInWithRedirect`

Comment: Thanks a lot Channing Huang. Understand better now.